# Efficient reliable incremental HTTP multi-file (or whole directory) upload software

Tags: http, upload, synchronization, file-upload, multifile-uploader

Imagine you have a web site that you want to send a lot of data. Say 40 files totaling the equivalence of 2 hours of upload bandwidth. You expect to have 3 connection losses along the way (think: mobile data connection, WLAN vs. microwave). You can't be bothered to retry again and again. This should be automated. Interruptions should not cause more data loss than neccessary. Retrying a complete file is a waste of time and bandwidth.

So here is the question: Is there a software package or framework that

1. synchronizes a local directory (contents) to the server via HTTP,
2. is multi-platform (Win XP/Vista/7, MacOS X, Linux),
3. can be delivered as one self-contained executable,
4. recovers partially uploades files after interrupted network connections or client restarts,
5. can be generated on a server to include authentication tokens and upload target,
6. can be made super simple to use

or what would be a good way to build one?

Options I have found until now:

- Neat packaging of `rsync`. This requires an rsync (server) instance on the server side that is aware of a privilege system.
- A custom Flash program. As I understand, Flash 10 is able to read a local file as a bytearray (indicated [here](http://blog.kukiel.net/2009/02/file-manipulation-client-side-with.html)) and is obviously able to speak HTTP to the originating server. Seen in [question 1344131](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344131/upload-image-thumbnail-to-server-without-uploading-whole-image) ("Upload image thumbnail to server, without uploading whole image").
- A custom native application for each platform.

Thanks for any hints!

Related work:

- HTML5 will allow multiple files to be uploaded or at least selected for upload "at once". [See here](http://rakaz.nl/2009/08/uploading-multiple-files-using-html5.html) for example. This is agnostic to the local files and does not feature recovery of a failed upload.
- [Efficient way to implement a client multiple file upload service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315884/efficient-way-to-implement-a-client-multiple-file-upload-service) basically asks for SWFUpload or YUIUpload (Flash-based multi-file uploaders, otherwise "stupid")
- A [comment in question 997253](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997253/non-flash-multi-file-upload-for-php/997306#997306) suggests [JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/index.html) - I think using a Java applet will at least require the user to grant additional rights so it can access local files
- [GearsUploader](http://bitbucket.org/kmike/gearsuploader/) seems great but requires Google Gears - that is going away soon

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best client side browser library to upload multiple files over http?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159600/what-is-the-best-client-side-browser-library-to-upload-multiple-files-over-http)